# Sci-fi movie or TV show shown in this Linus Tech Tips video

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

Recently, Linus Tech Tips covered a TV from China, and as part of the coverage they loaded up a segment from a Chinese movie through one of the apps. The segment can be found at 4:54 in the below video:

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot from the video]

Comment: "Long long ago, the monsters invaded the human dimension. The entire world was ruined" - I'm not sure how faithful a translation that it.

Comment: @Valorum yeah, I was mainly hoping someone would be able to recognize this from the scene itself.

Comment: Honestly it looks like a PC game rather than a film. Or a big dumb blockbuster where you can't actually tell that it's not a game

Comment: @Valorum I mean, it's being shown on a TV, and if the context is anything to go by it's from a streaming service with a per-movie purchase model. Sounds like it's most likely a movie or TV show.

Comment: Beijing Joy Pictures has 6 films on IMDB (https://www.imdb.com/search/title/?companies=co0319313) but none of them look immediately like this clip.

Answer (score 5):

This is [*GG Bond: Lollipop in Fantasy*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10885430/) (2019) by "Beijing Joy Pictures Co., Ltd". I found this by looking through the [list here for the company](https://www.thefilmcatalogue.com/companies/beijing-joy-pictures-co-ltd) and checking the listings. The above IMDb link also has the same cover art as what is clicked on in the video. You can see the clip from the TV at the start of this trailer: